# Dirichlet problem: estimatives

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation}\label{19}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
-\Delta v(x) & = & f(x), \ \ x \in \Omega\\
v(x) & = & 0, \ \ x \in \partial\Omega,
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
with $\Omega$ open, bounded and connected, whose boundary is $C^{2,\alpha}$. If $v$ is a solution to the previous problem, then $v \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$? Is there any a priori estimate that assures us that
$$||v||_{W^{2,p}(\Omega)} \leq c||H||_{L_p(\overline{\Omega})}?$$

I'm starting to study some articles involving elliptic equations and I came across these statements. I tried to identify such results in Gilbarg-Trudinger's book, but I couldn't find them. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma 9.17 in Gilbarg and Trudinger proves that if $\partial \Omega$ is $C^{1,1}$ then $$ \| v\| _{W^{2,p}(\Omega)} \leqslant C   \| \Delta v \| _{L^p(\Omega)} $$ for all $v\in W^{2,p}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$. This implies that $$ \| u\| _{W^{2,p}(\Omega)} \leqslant C   \| f \| _{L^p(\Omega)} $$ as required.